# Show that a set of polynomials make a linear space.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have a problem that states:
"Let P be the set of all polynomials of degree at most 2. Show that P is a linear space."

I know how to show that a set of vectors make a linear space with a certain number of dimensions, but am lost as to how to extend this concept to polynomials. How does a set of polynomials make a linear space?

Comment: "*I know how to show that a set of vectors make a linear space with a certain number of dimensions.*" -- What did you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the set of polynomials $\mathbb R[x]$ is a linear sapce then it suffices to prove that the given set usualy denoted by $\mathbb R_2[x]$ is a subsapce of $\mathbb R[x]$. For this purpose prove that $\mathbb R_2[x]$ isn't empty and invariant by linear combination.

Otherwise, you should verify that this set fulfills the axioms of linear space.

Answer (score 1):

Refer back to the definition of linearity, i.e. a space $V$ is linear iff $f,g \in V$ and $a$ is a scalar $\Rightarrow$ $af + g \in V$.

Answer (score 0):

A *linear space* structure (over $\Bbb R$) on a set $V$ consists of

- an *addition*-like operation $V\times V\to V$ (assigning the 'sum' of any two elements of $V$), denoted by $+$ infix and satisfying the usual equalities $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$ and $a+b=b+a$ for all $a,b\in V$.
- an operation $\Bbb R\times V\to V$ playing the role of *multiplication by scalar*, satisfying $1\cdot v=v$, $\ r\cdot (v+w)=r\cdot v+r\cdot w$, $\ (r+s)\cdot v=r\cdot v+s\cdot v\,$ and $\,(r\cdot s)\cdot v=r\cdot(s\cdot v)\,$ for any $r,s\in\Bbb R,\ v,w\in V$.

Now, addition and multiplication by real numbers *are defined* on the given set of polynomials (with degree $<k$), and as these arise from similar operation on real numbers, they satisfy all the equations above.